# python socket infinite loop after sending data

Tags: python, sockets, scripting

I'm working on a CTF challenge and I need to code a bot that does math problems. The way I'm doing it is by using sockets in python. My script seems to work once, but then it doesn't send or receive any data and it keeps listening. I tried putting print statements in the code to see where it was stuck, but none of the prints seem to be printing out after they are printed out 2 to 3 times.

Could someone help me figure out how to make the loop run forever so it can receive and send data?

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm using debian if it matters at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, re, time

FLAG = 'FLAG'
BOT = ('IP to server', port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(BOT)

while 1:
    string = ""
    while True:
        chunk = s.recv(4096)
        string += chunk
        if len(chunk) < 4096:
            break
        if len(string) <= 4096:
            if string != "":
                break

#       print "loop 1\n"
#       time.sleep(.5)
    for line in string.split("\n"):
#       print "loop 2\n"
        if FLAG in line:
            print line
        if re.search("([0-9])+", line):
            result = eval(line)
            print result
            s.send(str(result))
#   raw_input("enter:")

s.close()
```

Comment: I don't know enough about the server side to say too much, but you don't have any way to break out of this loop. If the other size closes, `recv` returns an empty string. But at `if len(chunk) < 4096:` you treat a close as valid data and continue to process. At a minimum check for an empty string. And then..., well you don't have any path to get out of that outer while...

Comment: You skip processing if you receive exactly 4096 bytes. Did you mean to read until you get 4096 bytes?

Comment: There is no way to get out of the main loop since I don't really want to escape it. I needed it go on forever until it cannot find any more `line` with numbers to `eval()`. I added a way to check for empty strings I'm going to edit the code here